# 500 Internal Server Error after Cookies has been Set (PHP)

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Now My Website Home page is loading but when logged in cookies has been set but it says

> **Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error**
>
> > misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please
> >     contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error
> >     occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the
> >     error.
> >
> > More information about this error may be available in the server error
> >     log.

I have tried both IE & Chrome --> Shows same error.

**System was working perfectly till yesterday! Don't know what happened now!**

In login setup page, i am using..
    setcookie("userid",$userid[1],time()+3600);
    setcookie("password",$password,time()+3600);

And after login it will redirect to next page which is containing following code...

```
<? ob_start(); ?>
<?php if (isset($_COOKIE["userid"]) and isset($_COOKIE["password"]))
  {//logged in;
  }
  else
  {
    die("You are not logged in...<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; url=index.php' />");
  }?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My site</title>
```

... and so on...

Comment: You should never store user credentials (username and password) in cookies. That is a very bad security practice. Use PHP cookie sessions instead. Like `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My host provider done the change to the php processor setting to ISAPI from fastcgi;

> It works now !

Answer (score 0):

If it was working before and suddenly stopped working: Was php upgraded and are short tags disabled in the new version?

Change `<?` on the first line to `<?php` to see if that is the problem.

You can also check the server error log for more details about the 500 error.

Comment: i am using remote host from a service provider.. how can i get the error log ?

Comment: i found it is not due to cookies; but other page which is not depending on cookies is also facing Internal Serve Error ! Any suggestion

Comment: @logan You need to get access to the error log, otherwise it will all just be speculation. You could also try to set `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` at the beginning of the first script to see if that shows you any more details.

Comment: My host provider done the change to the php processor setting to ISAPI from fastcgi; It works now !